# DxgiOuputDuplication texture frames to DirectX VideoProcessor

Tags: c++, directx-11, ms-media-foundation

I was playing with this project [DirectXVideoScreen](https://github.com/mofo7777/DirectXVideoScreen) because I am trying to find a way to convert RGBA to NV12 so I can make a video using the h264 transformation of my GPU. (You can only use the transformation when you have NV12 or YUV2 color format)

I have tried doing the color conversion using the Windows Media Foundation MFT (Video processor) but I am trying to go directly and use DirectX in order to have more control.

While you duplicate the screen the texture you get back is of type `DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM` and I have to transform it to  `DXGI_FORMAT_NV12`.

So I took the code from the project "D3D11VideoProcessor" and added the code from the "SimpleDesktopDuplication" project.

It is like this.

```
CD3D11VideoProcessor cD3D11VideoProcessor;
CSimpleDesktopDuplication cSimpleDesktopDuplication;
ID3D11Texture2D* output = NULL;

if (cSimpleDesktopDuplication.InitDesktopDuplication() == S_OK)
{
    output = cSimpleDesktopDuplication.ProcessDesktopDuplication();
}

if(cD3D11VideoProcessor.InitDXVA2(2560,1440, DXGI_FORMAT_NV12) == S_OK)
{
    cD3D11VideoProcessor.ProcessImageConversion(output, CONVERTED_IMAGE);
}
```

The problem (I think?) is that

```
m_pDXGIOutputDuplication->AcquireNextFrame(500, &FrameInfo, &pDXGIResource));
pDXGIResource->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), reinterpret_cast<void **>(&pScreenShotTexture2D)));
```

Returns a texture with the following flags.

```
Width: a00
Height: 5a0
MipLevels: 1
ArraySize: 1
Format: 57
Usage: 0
BindFlags: 28 // D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE
CPUAccessFlags: 0
MiscFlags: 2900
```

And here the code fails while executing
`m_pD3D11VideoContext->VideoProcessorBlt(m_pD3D11VideoProcessor, pD3D11VideoProcessorOutputView, 0, 1, &StreamData)`

```
HRESULT CD3D11VideoProcessor::ProcessImageConversion(ID3D11Texture2D* outputDuplicationTexture, LPCWSTR wszOutputImageFile)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    ID3D11VideoProcessorInputView* pD3D11VideoProcessorInputViewIn = NULL;
    ID3D11VideoProcessorOutputView* pD3D11VideoProcessorOutputView = NULL;
    ID3D11VideoDevice* pD3D11VideoDevice = NULL;
    ID3D11Texture2D* pOutTexture2D = NULL;

    IF_FAILED_RETURN(m_pD3D11VideoContext == NULL ? E_UNEXPECTED : S_OK);

    try
    {
        IF_FAILED_THROW(m_pD3D11Device->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID3D11VideoDevice), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pD3D11VideoDevice)));

        D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc2D;
        desc2D.Width = 2560;
        desc2D.Height = 1440;
        desc2D.MipLevels = 1;
        desc2D.ArraySize = 1;
        desc2D.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
        desc2D.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
        desc2D.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
        desc2D.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
        desc2D.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET;
        desc2D.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
        desc2D.MiscFlags = 0;

        D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc2Dtmp;
        outputDuplicationTexture->GetDesc(&desc2Dtmp);

        printf("Width: %x\n", desc2Dtmp.Width);
        printf("Height: %x\n", desc2Dtmp.Height);
        printf("MipLevels: %x\n", desc2Dtmp.MipLevels);
        printf("ArraySize: %x\n", desc2Dtmp.ArraySize);
        printf("Format: %x\n", desc2Dtmp.Format);
        printf("Usage: %x\n", desc2Dtmp.Usage);
        printf("BindFlags: %x\n", desc2Dtmp.BindFlags);
        printf("CPUAccessFlags: %x\n", desc2Dtmp.CPUAccessFlags);
        printf("MiscFlags: %x\n", desc2Dtmp.MiscFlags);

        D3D11_VIDEO_PROCESSOR_INPUT_VIEW_DESC pInDesc;
        ZeroMemory(&pInDesc, sizeof(pInDesc));
        pInDesc.FourCC = 0;
        pInDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_VPIV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
        pInDesc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;
        pInDesc.Texture2D.ArraySlice = 0;

        IF_FAILED_THROW(pD3D11VideoDevice->CreateVideoProcessorInputView(outputDuplicationTexture, m_pD3D11VideoProcessorEnumerator, &pInDesc, &pD3D11VideoProcessorInputViewIn));

        desc2D.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_NV12;

        IF_FAILED_THROW(m_pD3D11Device->CreateTexture2D(&desc2D, NULL, &pOutTexture2D));

        D3D11_VIDEO_PROCESSOR_OUTPUT_VIEW_DESC pOutDesc;
        ZeroMemory(&pOutDesc, sizeof(pOutDesc));
        pOutDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_VPOV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
        pOutDesc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;

        IF_FAILED_THROW(pD3D11VideoDevice->CreateVideoProcessorOutputView(pOutTexture2D, m_pD3D11VideoProcessorEnumerator, &pOutDesc, &pD3D11VideoProcessorOutputView));

        D3D11_VIDEO_PROCESSOR_STREAM StreamData;
        ZeroMemory(&StreamData, sizeof(StreamData));
        StreamData.Enable = TRUE;
        StreamData.OutputIndex = 0;
        StreamData.InputFrameOrField = 0;
        StreamData.PastFrames = 0;
        StreamData.FutureFrames = 0;
        StreamData.ppPastSurfaces = NULL;
        StreamData.ppFutureSurfaces = NULL;
        StreamData.pInputSurface = pD3D11VideoProcessorInputViewIn;
        StreamData.ppPastSurfacesRight = NULL;
        StreamData.ppFutureSurfacesRight = NULL;
                
                /*Error is here !!!*/
        IF_FAILED_THROW(m_pD3D11VideoContext->VideoProcessorBlt(m_pD3D11VideoProcessor, pD3D11VideoProcessorOutputView, 0, 1, &StreamData));

        IF_FAILED_THROW(CreateBmpFileFromYUVSurface(pOutTexture2D, wszOutputImageFile));
    }
    catch(HRESULT){}

    SAFE_RELEASE(pOutTexture2D);
    SAFE_RELEASE(outputDuplicationTexture);
    SAFE_RELEASE(pD3D11VideoProcessorOutputView);
    SAFE_RELEASE(pD3D11VideoProcessorInputViewIn);
    SAFE_RELEASE(pD3D11VideoDevice);

    return hr;
}
```

The error code is `0x80070057` meaning `E_INVALIDARG One or more arguments are invalid.`. I can not find the invalid arg :/

Can you help me ? or guide me ? Maybe I have to somehow change the `ID3D11Texture2D* outputDuplicationTexture` to match a simpler version of the texture (change misc params) ?

Thank you!

Comment: This is poorly documented, but is generally working on capable hardware (which is mostly everything). However you chose the hard path. First, most of the H.264 encoders are already offering RGB32 input support out of the box. Second, Media Foundation Video Processor MFT is offering you this conversion in a convenient way (actually wrapping the API you are trying to use directly; with fallback code path for software conversion). And then finally just you probably need to do additional texture copy because the one you get is incompatible and hence `E_INVALIDARG`.

Comment: Oh, and the fourth is that you are interested in using [debug layers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/overviews-direct3d-11-devices-layers#debug-layer) to get additional diagnostics in debug output.

Comment: I think that you shouldn't set: desc2D.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET; Set it to 0 instead. Also ZeroMemory desc2D in the beginning. Other than that I also set the following two on the output view description: OutputViewDesc.Texture2DArray.MipSlice = 0; and OutputViewDesc.Texture2DArray.FirstArraySlice = 0; even though it is also ZeroMemory'ed.